# Spring Boot + Kerberos + HDFS

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-boot, hdfs, kerberos

Is it possible to connect to HDFS (that has a Kerberos authentication) through Spring Boot? I want my application to be able to upload and download files to and from HDFS, and it has to go through Kerberos to do this. I have looked into Spring-Hadoop but couldn't find this specific use case.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Kerberos firewall" !! Kerberos is about **authentication**, not about filtering traffic... !

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I've edited it.

Comment: It would have to go through SPNEGO authentication. And Apache Knox can help that. Spring doesn't really matter here. Yes, you can use Java with a Kerberos Hadoop cluster. Does Spring support it? That's an implementation detail, but again, you don't need to use Spring